# Trying to setup user pool authentication for API Gateway

Tags: postman, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to setup security on an API using Cognito user pools. I'm getting back 401 Unauthorized.

The API and User Pools are existing, and I've been using the user pool to log into an application. I'm now trying to secure the API calls.

I created an authorizer on the API,

[image: Authorizer]

Then I added the authorizer to one GET method in the API

[image]

Then finally I tried to test the API in Postman. I'm using the AWS Signature authorization.

[image]

Calling the method returns 401. The method functioned before with no security, and turning off the authorizer makes it work again (without security).

Any ideas what step I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS Signature authorization is different than a Custom Authorizer.

The AWS Signature authorization (Postman) requests an AWS AccessKey and SecretKey to authenticate requests. This corresponds to [IAM Authentication](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-authentication-api-gateway/) in API Gateway. The AccessKey and SecretKey are received through IAM.

A Custom Authorizer takes a [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) called `#id_token` that is issued by your specified Cognito User Pool. To test the validity of the token, go to your custom authorizer and click test, and then copy and paste the token into the text area.

The way to perform the Custom Authorizer authentication is this:

1. obtain an `#id_token` from the your user pool by following [AWS Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-integration.html)
2. Configure API gateway with a Cognito custom Authorizer with your user pool as the source (Seems that you have done correctly)
3. Use `OAuth 2.0` as Authorization in postman, with your `#id_token` as the Access Token, Or add the header: `Authorization` with the value `Bearer` and the `#id_token`

Drop a comment if you want me to add the AWS Signature Auth Flow.

Answer (score 0):

For authorization using Postman when using Cognito user pools, chose `No Auth`. Then add a header `Authorization` (the value in token source field of your authorizer) and copy the `id_token` into that header value. I did not have to add anything else besides that to make it work (i.e. no bearer).