# Facebook/Google-only logins (no username/pwd) with AWS Cognito and React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'd like to build a react.js web app (and eventually a React Native iOS app too) that relies on Facebook (and later Google) for authentication without a username/password option.  I'm planning to host my server-side API (for both web and mobile versions of the app) in AWS API Gateway.

Now I'm trying to understand how AWS Cognito should fit into this app.

First, I'm assuming that I *don't* need a Cognito User Pool, because I only need federated social logins, not username/password logins. Is this assumption correct?

Second, I'm assuming that I *do* need a Cognito Identity Pool to easily authenticate my app's calls against the AWS API Gateway. Is this assumption correct?  And is it still correct if all of my app's access to AWS services will be via calls to AWS API Gateway endpoints?

Third, is there a public code sample somewhere of a social-only login use-case like this?  All the samples I could find in the AWS docs seem to assume that there's a Cognito User Pool being used.  The closest I could find is one [archived GitHub issue](https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/684) which seems close to my use-case, but it has no responses. ;-(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### First, I'm assuming that I don't need a Cognito User Pool, because I only need federated social logins, not username/password logins. Is this assumption correct?

[Federated identities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/identity-pools.html) are used to *"Provide temproary AWS credentials for users ..."* - So if you only want to provide temporary access through Federated Logins, then this assumption is **correct**.

If you want to manage the user groups and profiles as well as other user services you will need the user pool. However, based on your question, this is not a need.

#### Second, I'm assuming that I do need a Cognito Identity Pool to easily authenticate my app's calls against the AWS API Gateway. Is this assumption correct? And is it still correct if all of my app's access to AWS services will be via calls to AWS API Gateway endpoints?

Your assumption is **correct**, however, I want to add information about authenticating with API Gateway so you understand what other methods exist.

Cognito Identity Pools are one way to authenticate against API Gateway. There are three ways to authenticate with API Gateway

1. [Cognito Identity Pool Authenticated Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/identity-pools.html)
2. [API Gateway Identity Pool Authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html)
3. [API Gateway Lambda Authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html)

The primary difference between **Method 1** and **Method 2 &3** is the authentication pattern. The Cognito Identity Pool Authenticated Role Exchanges a [JWT](https://jwt.io/) for AWS [IAM credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html) that are used in API calls. In the other two methods the JWT is used as the authenticator. In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51307122/5787099) I explain the difference in more detail.

Because the Cognito Identity Pool returns AWS IAM credentials, it's uses are also broader. If your app will eventually require access to other AWS services (S3 for example) then Cognito Identity Pools would be the preferred method.

#### Third, is there a public code sample somewhere of a social-only login use-case like this?

Yes! I will try and provide some information on how to do this.

First, I would strongly suggest using the [AWS-Amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/index.html) library for login. This library provides methods to:

1. Authenticate with the Cognito User Pool
2. Make a Sig v4 Request to API Gateway using the AWS IAM credentials received from Authentication

For example, once you have Google (or Facebook) configured as an Identity Provider in your Identity Pool, AWS Amplify can easily allow you to perform the sign-in ([AWS Amplify Federated Identities](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/media/authentication_guide#enabling-federated-identities))

However, this can also be done without AWS Amplify using the [AWS JavaScript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-browser-credentials-federated-id.html). [Example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-browser-credentials-cognito.html):

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:1699ebc0-7900-4099-b910-2df94f52a030',
  Logins: { // optional tokens, used for authenticated login
    'graph.facebook.com': 'FBTOKEN',
    'www.amazon.com': 'AMAZONTOKEN',
    'accounts.google.com': 'GOOGLETOKEN'
  }
});
```

Recognize In both solutions (with AWS-Amplify and Without) the authentication is a two step process. First, your app must authenticate with Google or Facebook to receive a JWT. Second, this JWT is exchanged for IAM credentials that will be used for API calls.

Authentication Flow:

1. App authenticates with Identity provider (such as [FaceBook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web)) using the SDK for that identity provider. In response, the Identity provider sends a JWT that will be cached by the app.
2. App uses cached JWT to authenticate with AWS. If the Identity provider is configured in AWS, in response, AWS sends IAM credentials with the permissions granted to that identity provider.
3. IAM credentials are used to make Sig v4 request to API Gateway

This [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/facebook.html) goes into more detail for these steps in regarding Facebook.

In my own experience, I used [Okta](https://www.okta.com/) as an identity provider for my AWS Identity Pool using [OpenID](https://openid.net/). Similar to you, I did not use a User Pool, as these services were managed by Okta.

[This](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/cognito-user-pool-vs-identity-pool.html) is another great resource in understanding "serverless" Authentication.

Comment: Wow this is a great answer!  Exactly what I was looking for.  A few questions: 
1) re: "Similar to you, I did not use an Identity Pool", did you mean to say "User Pool" in that sentence?
2) re: "your app must authenticate with Google or Facebook to receive a JWT", does this JWT come from my Congnito Identity Pool, or is it simply passing through the JWT from Google/Facebook?  If the latter, how do I deal with the fact Facebook tokens are not JWTs? (see https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1011#issuecomment-398130347)

Comment: 1) Yes, I will update that! 2) In the example I am giving, I am using a 3rd party (IE FaceBook) as a Identity Provider - So the JWT comes from the Identity Provider. You will need to configure the identity provider (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web) first and then map it to the Cognito Identity Pool (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/facebook.html) .. I will try and update the answer to illustrate this flow

Comment: Also, I am looking into the github issue you referenced. I am not entirely sure the cause but in the comments it mentions requiring a `fb.api('/me', response)`. AWS amplify may not handle this correctly - I would recommend using the Facebook SDK to handle this part of the authentication