# Call an IAM protected API Gateway request from NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I am supposed to call an API Gateway method which is protected by IAM authorizer from a NodeJS server. Is there anyway I can directly call using AWS SDK leveraging roles? It seems like I will need to manually create an SigV4 signed request even if I am on the same AWS account?

Answer (score 0):

You have to sign requests using AWS signature version for and AWS credentials.

login to AWS and Go to AWS IAM and create a user with required access for accessing API Gateway.

[image]

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-iam-policy-examples.html

Now loginto postman

The AWS Signature authorization requests an AWS AccessKey and SecretKey to authenticate requests. This corresponds to IAM Authentication in API Gateway. The AccessKey and SecretKey are received through IAM.

[image]

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-authentication-api-gateway/
- https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/connect-to-api-gateway-with-iam-auth.html
- [Trying to setup user pool authentication for API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51297131/trying-to-setup-user-pool-authentication-for-api-gateway)